# Access local variable by name

Tags: lua

With globals you can use `_G[name]` to access the global variable `name` if you have a string "name":

```
function setGlobal(name, val)
   _G[name] = val
end
```

If you have

```
-- module.lua
local var1
local var2
```

there is no `_L` that would allow you to do the equivalent for locals:

```
function setLocal(name, val)
   _L[name] = val -- _L doesn't exist
end
```

Is there another way that you could access a local variable by string representing its name?

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @lhf I don't need it now, but I was just curious, since I have had a need for doing this with globals, and since I prefer to make variables local, what would I do if I needed to do this with locals?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `debug.getlocal()` and `debug.setlocal()` in the [`debug` library](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.10):

```
function setLocal(name, val)
    local index = 1
    while true do
        local var_name, var_value = debug.getlocal(2, index)
        if not var_name then break end
        if var_name == name then 
            debug.setlocal(2, index, val)
        end
        index = index + 1
    end
end
```

Test:

```
local var1
local var2
setLocal("var1", 42)
print(var1)
```

Output: `42`

Comment: +1 Good technique to have in one's arsenal. Even if uses the debug lib, at least it could be used in specific debugging circumstances. However because it uses debug, I won't accept it just yet (I suspect there is no other way, with out-of-the-box Lua, but I'd prefer not to give up hope just yet :).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend **not** using getLocal, it's a function in the `debug` library which should *never* be used in official commercial uses because it affects performance and opens huge vulnerabilities for hackers to exploit! Never depend on debug functions for your logic. 
If you really need this, then why not define a dictionary `_L`, then:

```
local _L = {}
_L.var1 = ...
_L.var2 = ...
```

The pattern above is not against the rules of Lua's design.

Comment: I'm not saying the debug functions are recommended, but it works when needed. And I'm sure OP already knows how to use a table to store variables like this.

Comment: It's a good try and you're right that you have to avoid using debug lib, but this technique does not solve the problem of accessing a local variable by string name; I specifically asked if there was any way to access a "local var1" via via "var1" as you could if it were not local (`_G["var1"]`). But I appreciate your contribution.