# How can a access a variable name using a string and concatination

Tags: variables, lua

I want to do something like the following:

```
local archetype = "melee"
local meleeNames = { x,y,z }

if itemNumber > # [archetype .. "Names"] then 
    itemNumber = # [archetype .. "Names"] 
end
```

However, I am not sure how to access the variable and this isn't it...

```
[archetype .. "Names"]
```

Thanks,
Gullie

Comment: You can't make up syntax like that. If the variable is global, use the `_G` table. But the variable is local in your code, in that case, read [Access local variable by name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22752379/1009479)

Answer (score 5):

As @yu-hao said in his comment, you'can make up a syntax like that. You can use nasty tricks to have a similar effect, but that's not recommended. Instead do something like this:

```
local archetypes = { meleeNames = { x, y, z },
                     ... others }
local archetype = "melee"

if itemNumber > #archetypes[archetype .. "Names"] then
  itemNumber = #archetypes[archetype .. "Names"]
end
```